# Proving this family is a basis for some topology.

Tags: general-topology

In Dugundji's book there's this problem:

> Let $C$ be the set of all continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$. For each $f\in C$, each finite set $x_1,...,x_n\in[0,1]$, and $\varepsilon>0$, let $U_{x_1,...,x_n}(f)=\{g:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\varepsilon, i=1,...,n\}$. Show **(a)** that these nbds *(neighbourhoods)* 
>   form a basis for some topology $\mathscr L$; **(b)** that $\mathscr L\subset \mathscr U$; and **(c)** that $\mathscr L$ and $\mathscr M$ are not related in the partial ordering of topologies in $C$.

**(a)** I think the way to got is using Theorem 3.2:
[image: I'm sorry for using an image, but this is pretty long]
Here I'll be considering $\mathscr B:=U_{x_1,...,x_n}$, and for short $U_{x_1,...,x_n}:=U_{x_i}$. So to use this first we have to see if it satisfies the hypothesis. To show that for each $(\alpha, \beta)\in C\times C$, and for each $f\in U_{x_i}(\alpha)\cap U_{x_i}(\beta)$, there exists some $U_{x_i}(g)$ such that $f\in U_{x_i}(g)\subset U_{x_i}(\alpha)\cap U_{x_i}(\beta)$. 

*So this is one of my questions, notation is very tricky, and I tend to misinterpret, what I've done so far is correct?*

So if $f\in U_{x_i}(\alpha)\cap U_{x_i}(\beta)$ then $|f(x_i)-\alpha(x_i)|<\varepsilon$ and $|f(x_i)-\beta(x_i)|<\varepsilon$, $\forall i=1,...,n$, so what I thought of doing was build the function $g$ like in the middle of $f, \alpha, \beta$ in those points $x_1,...,x_n$.

[image: another :P]

However, after a few experiments, I got to the conclusion that the only $g$ that could work like that, would be one where $|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|=0$, but I don't know if that's correct, I mean if anything I could just take $f=g$ and that's it!

**(b)** Obviously I haven't even finished **(a)**, but I don't know what $\mathscr U$ is, I looked in the whole section, and it doesn't says, the same goes in **(c)**, with $\mathscr M$.

**(c)** What does "partial ordering of topologies" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** First I would suggest that if you find your own notation confusing you should change it.  Of particular confusion is the overuse of "$x_i$" and omission of a distinct $\epsilon$ for each $U$.

Try something like this.  Let $x_1,...,x_m$, $y_1,...,y_n$, be sequences abbreviated by the notation $y_i$ and $x_i$.  Consider two functions $f_x, f_y$ and two real numbers $\epsilon_x, \epsilon_y >0$ used to define $U_{x_i}(f_x)$ and $U_{y_i}(f_y)$ respectively.  Your goal is to find a sequence $z_1,...,z_s$ (abbreviated $z_i$), a function $f_z$, and an $\epsilon_z >0$ such that 
$$U_{z_i}(f_z) \subset U_{x_i}(f_x) \cap U_{y_i}(f_y).$$

**b)** I would guess that $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{M}$ are other topologies defined on $C$ by the author.

**c)** Topologies are subsets of the power set so they are naturally partially ordered by inclusion of subsets.

Comment: Using the proper notations makes a lot of the problems disappear, specially while learning topology, at the end the problem wasn't that hard. $\mathscr U$, $\mathscr M$ did turned out to be topologies defined by the author. Thanks..